# How can I replace the letters in a String?

Tags: java

I am supposed to write code that replaces a letter in an input. For example, if the word is "hello" and the letter to replace is "l" and put "y" it would make "heyyo". I just don't know what to do after the user inputs.

```
     import java.util.Scanner;
      public class Letter
      {
          public static void main(String[] args)
          {
         // Ask the user for 3 things: their word, letter they want to replace,
         // and replacing letter.
         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Enter your word:");
         String word = input.nextLine();
         System.out.println();

         System.out.println("Enter the letter you want to replace:");
         String letter = input.nextLine();
         System.out.println();

         System.out.println("Enter the replacing letter:");
         String replace = input.nextLine();
         System.out.println();
         // Call the method replaceLetter and pass all 3 of these items to it for 
         // string processing.

     }

     // Modify this method so that it will take a third parameter from a user that is the String 
     //they 
     //want
     //to replace letterToReplace with. This method should return the modified String.
     public static int replaceLetter(String word, String letterToReplace, String replacement)
     {

         int count = 0;
         for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
         {
             if(word.substring(i, i+1).equals(letterToReplace))
             {
                 count++;
             }
         }
         return count;
     }
 }
```

Comment: `"hello".replace('l', 'y')`;

Comment: @YCF_L I can't hard code it, it has to be any word and any letters

Comment: Have you read the documentation for String?

Comment: You can just use `return replaceLetter.replace(letterToReplace, replacement);`

Answer (score 1):

Try doing the next, replacing the char at the position if it is the same as the letter to replace.

```
   for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
   {
        if(word.charAt(i) == letterToReplace)
        {
              word = word.substring(0, i) 
              + replacement
              + word.substring(i + 1); 
              count++;
         }
   }
```

Or you could just do the next:

```
 word = word.replace(letterToReplace, replacement);
```

Answer (score 1):

YCF_L is correct, the best way would be with replace.  If you need to do things programatically for some reason, this will work:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // Ask the user for 3 things: their word, letter they want to replace,
    // and replacing letter.
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your word:");
    String word = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Enter the letter you want to replace:");
    String letter = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Enter the replacing letter:");
    String replace = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println();
    // Call the method replaceLetter and pass all 3 of these items to it for
    // string processing.
    System.out.println(replaceLetter(word, letter, replace));

}

// Modify this method so that it will take a third parameter from a user that is the String
//they
//want
//to replace letterToReplace with. This method should return the modified String.
public static String replaceLetter(String word, String letterToReplace, String replacement)
{
    //Short way:
    String wayOne = word.replace(letterToReplace, replacement);

    //Long way:
    String wayTwo = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++){
        if(word.charAt(i) == letterToReplace.charAt(0)){
            wayTwo += replacement;
        } else {
            wayTwo += Character.toString(word.charAt(i));
        }
    }

    return wayOne + " VS " + wayTwo;
}
```